# Insert missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have a sql server 2008 r2 table that contains thousands of records which have been updated by a separate program.  Due to an oversight there are a series of missing records.  I need to insert the missing records into the database.  If the records exists (ANumber and Stage match the table of possible missing records) then go to the next record, if it doesn't exist insert the record (ANumber, Stage, field3 through field10.)

What I was thinking of doing was first create the missing records table (fields 1 -10).  Name the table tbMissRec.  My existing table is MstrAnno.

This is where I am not sure about the syntax.  I have seen merge commands but what I think of is if then kind of logic

```
If (tbMissRec.ANumber = MstrAnno.ANumber) and (tbMissRec.Stage =
MstrAnno.Stage) then Else insert into MstrAnno
tbMissRec.ANumber,tbMissRec.Stage, etc)
```

I am sure that this is not the right syntax, but I think that the logic is evident.

I just need to insert records if they don't exist.

Comment: Could you add some data sample of what you have and what you desire to get?

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you trying to populate table tbMissRec?  If so, from where are you attempting to get the data?

Comment: I am trying to update the table MstrAnno.  The table was missing data from an import procedure that was done a month ago.  I am trying to go back to the records and update the table where it is missing data.  There are 35K records in the table and I have 8K that occurred in the date range we are trying to fix.  Only the records where there is not a match to ANumber and Stage need to be inserted into the table.

Comment: Here is the code I was trying INSERT INTO MasterAnnotation
    SELECT A.[AdDate],A.Page_ID,A.Status,A.[AnnotationNumber],A.[AnnotationBy],A.[RoleDescription],A.[AnnotationDate],A.[AnnotationType],A.[BusinessUnit],A.[ActualAgencyError],A.[ErrorType],A.[AnnotationComments],A.[TeamComments],A.Client,A.Activity
    FROM dbo.MissRec A
    LEFT JOIN MasterAnnotation B ON B.AnnotationNumber = A.[AnnotationNumber] AND B.AnnotationDate = A.[AnnotationDate]
    WHERE B.AnnotationNumber IS NULL

Comment: I found the problem.  I need to define the column names in the insert into statement.  Once I did that the insert happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this format as it's easy to comment out the insert and verify the data that would be inserted. Also, you should specify column names in your inserts and selects.

```
INSERT INTO MstrAnno (ANumber,Stage)
    SELECT A.ANumber,A.Stage
    FROM tbMissRec A
    LEFT JOIN MstrAnno B ON B.ANumber = A.ANumber AND B.Stage = A.Stage
    WHERE B.ANumber IS NULL
```

Comment: If you are going to lecture about specifying column names, you should not select * yourself.

Comment: @DanBracuk Seeing as how the original question didn't specify all of the columns, I don't see how I could do that unless "etc" is a column name... updated all the same.

Comment: INSERT INTO MasterAnnotation
    SELECT A.[AdDate],A.Page_ID,A.Status,A.[AnnotationNumber],A.[AnnotationBy],A.[RoleDescription],A.[AnnotationDate],A.[AnnotationType],A.[BusinessUnit],A.[ActualAgencyError],A.[ErrorType],A.[AnnotationComments],A.[TeamComments],A.Client,A.Activity
    FROM dbo.MissRec A
    LEFT JOIN MasterAnnotation B ON B.AnnotationNumber = A.[AnnotationNumber] AND B.AnnotationDate = A.[AnnotationDate]
    WHERE B.AnnotationNumber IS NULL                                                                I am getting an error Column Name or number does not match definition?

Comment: Found the problem.  I need to define the column names in the insert into statement.  Once I did that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
INSERT INTO MstrAnno
SELECT *
FROM tbMissRec A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MstrAnno
                 WHERE ANumber = A.ANumber 
                 AND Stage = A.Stage)
```